# modx Evolution: куда добавить вызов файла с плагином?

Tags: modx, evolution

Есть доставшийся в наследство код. Плагин синхронизирует карточку товара с другим сайтом и разделен на две части.
Первая срабатывает по сохранению карточки товара и добавляет обновленные данные товара в кеш и какую-то кастомную таблицу в БД. Она работает.
Вторая должна забирать из таблицы эти данные и отправлять их по курлу на другой сайт. Эта часть не работает и есть файл с точкой входа в эту часть. Но не понятно, где она была подключена. Бэкапов нет.
Я не специалист в modx, мне просто баг дали пофиксить и я совершенно не представляю, какие есть варианты куда впихнуть вызов этого файла.
Подскажите, пожалуйста
Спасибо

Comment: Плагины обычно срабатывают на какие-то системные события в MODX, а какие у вас события? Либо в настройках плагина либо в коде это видно. Если вы про это "подключение". Содержимое файла также  наличии?

Comment: OnDocFormSave. Он и срабатывает, но только первая часть - добавление данных в таблицу для последующей обработки. А вторая часть должна уже запускать обработку, но она нигде не вызывается. В этом и проблема, я понятия не имею куда это воткнуть. Есть ли какая-то возможность добавить этот кусок куда-то в отложенный вызов? Может, где-то есть вызов кода по таймеру, или какой-то асинхрон?